# como tomar un dato de un objeto json en ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

tengo este codigo para crear una tabla e insertarle los datos del arreglo tipo json:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Manager/metricsAdvocates',
    type:  'post',
    data:  {'sup':sup, 'dateM':dateM},
    dataType: 'json',

     success: function(response){

 var i=0;
 var vhur1 = "";
 var attendance1 = "";
 var advocate1= "";

       $.each(response,function(index,data){
          var data = JSON.stringify(response);

         vhur1 = data[i]["vhur"];
         attendance1 = data[i]["advocate"];
         advocate1 = data[i]["attendance"];

              var tabla = "";
              tabla+="<tr>";
              tabla+="<td id='vhur' class='text-center'>"+vhur1+" </td>";
              tabla+="<td id='advocate' class='text-center'> "+attendance1+" </td>";
              tabla+="<td id='attendance' class='text-center'>"+advocate1+"</td>";

              tabla+="</tr>";
            $('#tableAtt').append(tabla);

                          i++;
        });
      },
     });
```

el problema es que me sale que lo que estoy insertando en el  esta indefinido, como si esa clave no existiera. en consola el me imprime el arreglo, pero de tipo json, y yo quiero tomar un dato que esta dentro de ese arreglo con esta linea:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

asi me sale la tabla donde dice undefined  necesito los valores de del objeto json, y las claves son el nombre de las culumnas osea vhur, advocates, attendance en estas tres lineas le hago referencia a la clve de cada uno y lo guardo en una variable que es la que voy a mostrar en el td.

```
         vhur1 = data[i]["vhur"];
         attendance1 = data[i]["advocate"];
         advocate1 = data[i]["attendance"];
```

si es asi que tomo una dato del objeto tipo json o hay otra manera  ?

Comment: Hola, podrias mostrar como se forma tu json , muestra cual tu json que se forma.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te sobra la línea

```
var data = JSON.stringify(response);
```

Lo que quieres es tener los datos, que ya están en la respuesta (`response`). Al hacer un `JSON.stringify` lo que haces es transformar los datos en un string, con lo que es imposible que algo como

```
vhur1 = data[i]["vhur"];
```

te de algo que no sea `undefined`

Comment: mil graciasss, asi lo solucione...